# How do I negate a ZSH regular expression test?

Tags: regex, zsh

How do I negate the ZSH regex operator?

I'd like to do something like:

```
if [[ $host !~ '^myhost[0-9]+$' ]]
then
    # Do stuff
    # ...
fi
```

...or:

```
if [[ !($host =~ '^myhost[0-9]+$') ]]
then
    # Do stuff
    # ...
fi
```

...but it doesn't look like ZSH implements any sort of regex negation operator.  Is there an easier way than this:

```
if [[ $host =~ '^myhost[0-9]+$' ]]
then
else
    # Do stuff
    # ...
fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how zsh works, but you might try the regex: `'^(?!myhost[0-9]+$).+$'` It should match all but `myhost[0-9]+`.

Comment: You gave the answer yourself. Your second proposal is correct, you only missed a blank after the exclamation mark: `if [[ ! ($host =~ '^myhost[0-9]+$') ]]`.

Comment: Thanks, @mpy!  I forgot about zsh's (and all shells, AFAIK) sensitivity to spaces in condition statements.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A negation of the entire test would be the easiest. Mostly because it's easy to remember and doesn't depend on any specific condition syntax:

```
if ! [[ $host =~ '^myhost[0-9]+$' ]]
then
    # Do stuff
    # ...
fi
```